# Within-group and between-group variation in real life processes?

Tags: references, quality-control

In the context of Statistical Process Control (SPC), control charts are used to monitor a process over time and detect shifts in the mean or variation. The traditional Shewhart $\bar{X}$ charts makes use of (rational) group means to monitor the process mean over time. However, one of the assumptions is that there is no between-group variation. While this is the ideal scenario for a process, it does not seem to be realistic in the real world. To be precise, the underlying model that is used in traditional charts is
$$X_{ij} = \mu + \varepsilon_{ij} \tag{M1},$$
where $\mu$ is the process mean and $\varepsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is a random variable. This model fails to account for between-group variation.
The article *Statistical process control with several components of common cause variability* (Woodall and Thomas, 1995) discusses this topic, along with an example.  They propose the model
$$X_{ij} = \mu + \beta_{i}+\varepsilon_{ij} \tag{M2},$$
where now $\beta_i \sim N(0,\sigma_{B}^2)$ is a random variable that accounts for the between-group variation.They also refer to other specific examples presented by other authors.
However, I was wondering whether there have been larger and/or more recent studies regarding this topic. Ideally, studies that use data from the industry to show that between-group variation is usually present. I would greatly appreciate any references or ideas!

Answer (score 5):

These models are referred to as linear mixed effect or random effects models in general.

A search for articles in this area yield a couple of potential references:

1. [Monitoring of Linear Profiles Using Linear Mixed Model in the Presence of Measurement Errors](https://www.mdpi.com/1993582)
2. [Statistical Process Control Charts as a Tool for Analyzing Big Data](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-41573-4_7)
3. [Nonparametric Profile Monitoring by Mixed Effects Modeling](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27867245)
4. [Statistical Process Control Methods for Network Monitoring Using Generalized Linear Mixed Models](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/27z9q5qp)
5. [Statistical process control methods for network monitoring using generalized linear mixed models](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christina-Staudhammer/publication/228352351_Mixed-Model_Development_for_Real-Time_Statistical_Process_Control_Data_in_Wood_Products_Manufacturing/links/02bfe51015e354b1a7000000/Mixed-Model-Development-for-Real-Time-Statistical-Process-Control-Data-in-Wood-Products-Manufacturing.pdf)

Another method is to look at papers that cite the paper you reference:

1. Daewon Yang, Jinsu Park, Hayang Park, Sungki Hong, Jongmin Kim, Seonghui Huh, Eunkyung Kim, Jaeyong Jeong & Yeonseung Chung. (2023) Robust control chart based on mixed-effects modeling framework: A case study in NAND flash memory industry. Quality Engineering 0:0, pages 1-11.
2. Rob Goedhart & William H. Woodall. (2022) Monitoring proportions with two components of common cause variation. Journal of Quality Technology 54:3, pages 324-337.
3. T. C. Chang & F. F. Gan. (2004) Shewhart Charts for Monitoring the Variance Components. Journal of Quality Technology 36:3, pages 293-308.
4. Stephen M. Scariano & Jaimie L. Hebert. (2003) Adapting EWMA Control Charts for Batch-Correlated Data. Quality Engineering 15:4, pages 545-556.
5. Thomas C. Maness, Robert A. Kozak & Christina Staudhammer. (2003) Applying Real-Time Statistical Process Control to Manufacturing Processes Exhibiting Between and Within Part Size Variability in the Wood Products Industry. Quality Engineering 16:1, pages 113-125.